# Force compilation event without dependent static function definition in Java

Tags: java

Since a static function call is translated into a static invocation bytecode regardless of how the definition exists... is there some way to force a caller of a static function to compile successfully even when the target function and class don't exist yet?

I want to be able to compile calls to functions that don't exist yet. I need to tell the compiler to trust me that at runtime, I'll have them properly defined and in the classpath so go ahead and compile it for now.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just mock or stub them?

Comment: You can achieve this with a byte code engineering library (e.g. ASM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflectively yes, but not via a regular call.

The call requires an entry in the string pool that includes the method name *and parameter types* so the compiler needs to be able to decide on a signature for the method.

> ## [invokestatic <method-spec>](https://www.vmth.ucdavis.edu/incoming/Jasmin/ref--34.html)
>
> <method-spec> is a method specification. It is a single token made up of three parts: a classname, a methodname and a descriptor. e.g.
>
> ```
>  java/lang/System/exit(I)V
> ```
>
> is the method called "exit" in the class called "java.lang.System", and it has the descriptor "(I)V" (i.e. it takes an integer argument and returns no result).

Consider

```
AClass.aStaticMethod(42)
```

Without knowing anything about `AClass`, it could be a call to any of

1. `AClass.aStaticMethod(int)`
2. `AClass.aStaticMethod(int...)`
3. `AClass.aStaticMethod(long)`
4. `AClass.aStaticMethod(long...)`
5. ditto for `float` and `double`
6. `AClass.aStaticMethod(Integer)`
7. `AClass.aStaticMethod(Number)`
8. `AClass.aStaticMethod(Comparable<? extends Integer>)`
9. `AClass.aStaticMethod(Object)`
10. `AClass.aStaticMethod(Serializable)`

and probably a few others that I've missed.

Answer (score 2):

> ... is there some way to force a caller of a static function to compile successfully even when the target function and class don't exist yet?

No.  When compiling a method call, the compiler needs to check that the name, argument types, result type, exceptions and so on of the called method.  Since you are asking about a static method, this information can only defined in one place ... the class that declares the static method.  There is no work-around for this if you want static type-safety.

> I need to tell the compiler to trust me that at runtime ...

It is not that simple:

- You haven't told the compiler what the method signature *should* be.  The compiler needs to be told, because is not possible to accurately infer the signature from the call.
- The Java platform is designed to be robust, and "just trust me" could lead to catastrophic runtime failures.

---

If you are willing to sacrifice compile-time type safety and eschew the convenience / simplicity / readability of statically typed code, then reflection is an option.  But I can't think of any other options that would work.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could declare interfaces that have the methods and code against them, then use the [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory) pattern to provide implementations at runtime.

[Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) use this approach.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels skimmed the question. Thought he was talking about static binding. Still, this answer is not completely without merit, because it's probably what he *should* be doing and not using static methods.